# text recognition from image

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

How to recognise the text from handwriting?

I tried teseract libraries (version 2) but that is not too good. Its updated versions are not working well. And I have downloaded one demo project pocket OCR but that also not compiling.
I have compiled and integrated tesseract libraries but now it is giving me linking error as follows

```
    Ld /Users/Arkenea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCR-airiipqjvidtcogttlxdbnqufnnl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OCR.app/OCR normal i386
    cd "/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/Arkenea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCR-airiipqjvidtcogttlxdbnqufnnl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2" "-L/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/../../tesseract-ocr-svn" "-L/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/../../tesseract-ocr-svn/outdir" "-L/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib" -F/Users/Arkenea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCR-airiipqjvidtcogttlxdbnqufnnl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Arkenea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCR-airiipqjvidtcogttlxdbnqufnnl/Build/Intermediates/OCR.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OCR.build/Objects-normal/i386/OCR.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30102 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework MessageUI -ltesseract_api -ltesseract_ccstruct -ltesseract_ccutil -ltesseract_classify -ltesseract_cutil -ltesseract_dict -ltesseract_image -ltesseract_textord -ltesseract_training -ltesseract_viewer -ltesseract_wordrec -ltesseract_main -llept.2.0.0 -llept.2 -llept -llept -ltesseract.3.0.1 -ltesseract.3 -ltesseract -ltesseract -o /Users/Arkenea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCR-airiipqjvidtcogttlxdbnqufnnl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OCR.app/OCR

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/../../tesseract-ocr-svn'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/../../tesseract-ocr-svn/outdir'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_api.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_ccstruct.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_ccutil.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_classify.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_cutil.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_dict.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_image.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_textord.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_training.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_viewer.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_wordrec.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/libtesseract_main.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib/liblept.2.0.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib/liblept.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib/liblept.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib/libtesseract.3.0.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Arkenea/Desktop/suraj/notepad/rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9 2/lib/libtesseract.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::End()", referenced from:
      -[OCRDisplayViewController dealloc] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()", referenced from:
      -[OCRDisplayViewController viewDidLoad] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, GenericVector<STRING> const*, GenericVector<STRING> const*, bool)", referenced from:
      tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*) in OCRDisplayViewController.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TesseractRect(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      -[OCRDisplayViewController readAndProcessImage:] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
      -[OCRDisplayViewController threadedReadAndProcessImage:] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone help me or point me to some great ressources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that we have to set some settings in it
 like
  tesseract->Init([dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "eng");
        tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.!@#$%^&*()_+/{}|:?<>,~`");
        tesseract->AllWordConfidences();

give it whitelist as your reqirement

and set mode to default 
or as per your requirment